# beforeunload event doesn't fire on Firefox

Tags: javascript, events, firefox

For example, 2 tabs are opened in Firefox, one targeting page A and the other targeting page B. Page A has added a "beforeunload" event listener.

If I move to another URL on viewing page A, the event fires.

If I close page A tab on viewing page A, the event fires.

If I close page A tab on viewing page B, the event **doesn't** fire as expected.

If I close Firefox (Alt + F4) on viewing page A, the event fires.

However, if I close Firefox on viewing page B, the event **doesn't** fire as expected.

Is it a feature or a bug? Or am I doing something wrong?

(Tested on Firefox 30.* and 3.*)

Comment: This is only a problem in FF 30?

Comment: It is what my test was based. I did a further for earlier version (3.0) and it also happens. (Updated the question)

Answer (score 0):

Also, this is true as far as I know.
If I close page A tab while being on page B, the event doesn't fire.

I think it is a "Feature"

Comment: You are right, in this case the event doesn't fire. Anyway, I'd like to know why this feature? It doesn't seem so reasonable, does it?

Comment: JavaScript seems to switch itself off as soon as you are not on "page A" to save CPU.

Comment: I tried out something and I noticed that JavaScript doesn't switch itself off. Maybe it has to do with something else?